# Select query for two bits of data

Tags: mysql

The table (userData) looks like this:

```
userId    property    value
1         AGE         28
1         GENDER      M
2         AGE         28
2         GENDER      F
3         AGE         29
3         GENDER      F
4         AGE         29
4         GENDER      F
```

So I'd like to get something like:

```
Gender    Age    Count
M         28     1
F         28     1
F         29     2
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: You are going to hate yourself over and over for that table structure. Abandon it before it is too late to change it.

Comment: +1 for @JohnFx. What you have there is the EAV (Entity-attribute-value) model. Generally considered to be an anti-pattern.

Comment: P.S. @genevish Once you have an answer that works, you should mark one of the answers as correct but clicking one of the ticks to the left of their answer

Comment: Marked the answer as correct.  Thanks.  Also, I hated the table structure the minute I saw it, but I didn't develop it.  I'm just tasked with running reports...  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
    ud1.value AS gender,
    ud2.value AS age,
    COUNT(*) AS c
FROM userData ud1
JOIN userData ud2 ON
    ud1.userId = ud2.userId AND
    ud2.property = 'AGE'
WHERE ud1.property = 'GENDER'
GROUP BY gender, age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Not tested
SELECT *
  FROM userData age INNER JOIN
       userData gender ON gender.userId = age.userId
 WHERE age.property = 'AGE'
   AND gender.property = 'GENDER'
```

You'll get

```
userId    property    value   userId    property    value   
1         AGE         28      1         GENDER      M
2         AGE         28      2         GENDER      F
3         AGE         29      3         GENDER      F
4         AGE         29      4         GENDER      F
```

That done, you can COUNT() (not tested):

```
  SELECT age.value, gender.value, COUNT(*)
    FROM userData age INNER JOIN
         userData gender ON gender.userId = age.userId
   WHERE age.property = 'AGE'
     AND gender.property = 'GENDER'
GROUP BY age.value, gender.value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Gender, Age, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM
        (
            SELECT  UserID,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN property = 'Gender' THEN value END) Gender,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN property = 'Age' THEN value END) Age
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY UserID
        ) s
GROUP   BY Gender, Age
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a636/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════╦═════╦════════════╗
║ GENDER ║ AGE ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠════════╬═════╬════════════╣
║ M      ║  28 ║          1 ║
║ F      ║  28 ║          1 ║
║ F      ║  29 ║          2 ║
╚════════╩═════╩════════════╝
```